# NativeScript Extension VS Code Debugging: How to disable --debug-brk?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

It's quite cumbersome if you always land in `ts_helpers.js` at the first line in debug sessions.

I already encountered `"tnsArgs": "xxx"` in the extension [extension docs](http://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/visual-studio-code-extension). Debug break at first line can be activated with [--debug-brk](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/debug/debug-cli).

So my starting point for an entry in the `launch.json` is something like `"tnsArgs": "--debug-brk"`. I also get the warning

> Incorrect type. Expected "array"

, which results in an execution error.

So what must i set in tnsArgs to **disable** --debug-brk on Ubuntu/Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work automatically with the most recent version (0.5.1) if --debug-brk is not specified.

Additional CLI args can be appended like above with `tnsArgs`. The vs code warning, that an array is expected, can be ignored.

My current working configuration is the following, which also enables live debugging - awesome and fast.

```
{
            "name": "Sync on Android",
            "type": "nativescript",
            "platform": "android",
            "request": "launch",
            "appRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "diagnosticLogging": false,
            "emulator": false,
            "rebuild": false,
            "tnsArgs": "--no-rebuild --watch"
        },
```